# Google Cloud Translation API react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, google-cloud-translate

I use the Google Cloud translation API for my react-native app to translate the text. In `translateText` function, the header has the key that generates by Google Cloud SDK shell manually, so when I rebuild the app, this key is inactive and the text can not be translated. I use this API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text.

Here is my code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleProp,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ToastAndroid,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Textarea from 'react-native-textarea';

import usePreferenceContext from '~/hooks/usePreferenceContext';

import getImage from '~/libs/getImage';

import IconCopy from '~/resources/Icons/IconCopy';
import IconDropdown from '~/resources/Icons/IconDropdown';
import IconShare from '~/resources/Icons/IconShare';
import IconStar from '~/resources/Icons/IconStar';
import IconSwap from '~/resources/Icons/IconSwap';
import IconVoice from '~/resources/Icons/IconVoice';
import { useAppTheme } from '~/resources/theme';

import { RootNavigatorNavProps } from '~/navigation/RootNavigator';

import HistoryTrans from '../components/History/historyTrans';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomePage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const actionButton = usePreferenceContext();
  const dataLanguageInput = actionButton.result.languageSelect;
  const dataLanguageOutPut = actionButton.result.languageSelectOutput;
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const theme = useAppTheme();
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
  const [textOutPut, setTextOutPut] = useState('');
  const navigation = useNavigation<RootNavigatorNavProps>();
  const data = {
    title:
      'This is the first workshop dedicated to new employees since June of this year This is the first workshop dedicated to new employees since June of this year',
    description:
      'This is the first workshop dedicated to new employees since June of this year This is the first workshop dedicated to new employees since June of this year',
    active: false,
    time: '24/12/2023',
  };
  const handleCopyInput = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(textInput);
    ToastAndroid.show('Text copied to clipboard!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  };
  const onChangeInput = (e: any) => {
    setTextInput(e);
  };
  const onChangeOutPut = (e: any) => {
    setTextOutPut(e);
  };
  const handleCopy = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(textOutPut);
    ToastAndroid.show('Text copied to clipboard!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  };

  const handleTrans = async () => {
    if (textInput) {
      const translatedText = await translateText(textInput, dataLanguageOutPut.countyCode);
      setTextOutPut(translatedText);
    } else {
      console.log('typing to translate');
    }
  };


  const styleContainer = useMemo<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>(
    () => [
      {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
      },
    ],
    [theme],
  );

const translateText = async (text, targetLanguage) => {
  console.log(text, 'text');
  console.log(targetLanguage, 'targetLanguage');
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',
      {
        q: text,
        target: targetLanguage,
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ya29.a0AfB_byBW4x4jeQ_fFiRXKH2pZlxz-l0YdFswol81M8S1CNPkPtMapNEJNwYjGCCKNpxhEWJsmi7c4sSPkAU-lgzQakFtGeb71SnCGnQ7IIk8Zl7JWcLV2WahWxm_PsMiq44FPUardFE_AJJQC0KxEYR0_1mks85sPg4Um4aRXdcaCgYKAaQSARMSFQHGX2MiDRmtAuMhNdctGYPrsAKYpQ0178`, "x-goog-user-project": "translation-app-410307"}
      }
    );
    return response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during translation:', error);
    return '';
  }
};
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styleContainer}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          paddingHorizontal: 24,
          paddingTop: Platform.select({
            ios: 0,
            android: 40,
          }),
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            paddingBottom: 24,
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: '#000000',
              fontSize: 24,
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontWeight: '700',
            }}>
            {t('Translator')}
          </Text>
          <View />
        </View>
        <>
          <ScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  width: '40%',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  height: 48,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate('Language', { data: 'false' })
                  }
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      padding: 12,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                      <View style={{ paddingRight: 8 }}>
                        <Image
                          source={dataLanguageInput.image}
                          style={{ width: 24, height: 16 }}
                        />
                      </View>

                      <Text>{dataLanguageInput.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <IconDropdown />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#2665EF',
                  width: 48,
                  height: 48,
                  borderRadius: 99,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <IconSwap />
              </View>

              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  width: '40%',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  height: 48,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate('Language', { data: 'true' })
                  }
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      padding: 12,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                      <View style={{ paddingRight: 8 }}>
                        <Image
                          source={dataLanguageOutPut.image}
                          style={{ width: 24, height: 16 }}
                        />
                      </View>
                      <Text>{dataLanguageOutPut.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <IconDropdown />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={{ paddingTop: 24 }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    paddingHorizontal: 16,
                    borderRadius: 12,
                    paddingVertical: 12,
                  }}>
                  <Textarea
                    containerStyle={styles.textareaContainer}
                    onChangeText={(e: any) => onChangeInput(e)}
                    placeholder={'Typing to be able to translate 。。。'}
                    placeholderTextColor={'#c7c7c7'}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}

                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#A0A0A0',
                      width: '100%',
                      height: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      paddingTop: 14,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    }}>
                    <IconVoice />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCopyInput}>
                      <View style={{ paddingLeft: 24 }}>
                        <IconCopy />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleTrans}>
                <View
                  style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: textInput ? '#2665EF' : '#A0A0A0',
                      width: 154,
                      height: 48,
                      borderRadius: 12,
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      marginVertical: 12,
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: '#fff',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: '900',
                      }}>
                      Translate
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    paddingHorizontal: 16,
                    borderRadius: 12,
                    paddingVertical: 12,
                  }}>
                  <Textarea
                    containerStyle={styles.textareaContainer}
                    onChangeText={(e: any) => onChangeOutPut(e)}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                    editable={false}
                    value = {textOutPut}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#A0A0A0',
                      width: '100%',
                      height: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      paddingTop: 14,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    }}>
                    <IconStar />
                    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 24 }}>
                      <IconShare />
                    </View>
                    <IconVoice />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCopy}>
                      <View style={{ paddingLeft: 24 }}>
                        <IconCopy />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  paddingVertical: 12,
                }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontWeight: '400' }}>
                  {t('Recent')}
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('History')}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: '400',
                      color: '#2665EF',
                    }}>
                    {t('View more')}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            <HistoryTrans
              title={data.title}
              description={data.description}
              active={data.active}
              time={data.time}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textareaContainer: {
    height: 120,
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```